# Github: using checkout wrong?

Tags: git, github

Assuming I create a project, and create a branch called `branch1`.

After a enough modifications that `branch1` and `master` are both very obviously different, i want to go back to `master` and test the two independently.

I used `git checkout master` and it brought me to the master branch but also changed the files within master to match `branch1`.

What am I suppose to use to switch branches without changing any files between the two.

Comment: You didn't do a commit when you were on `branch1`.

Answer (score 1):

> but also changed the files within master to match branch1.

That shouldn't have happened. Probably you haven't properly added the modified files and/or committed them to `branch1` in the first place.

Use `gitk --all` command to review what you have uploaded to git so far and search for files that you have changed but are not shown on any commit.